# Diff in single column data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the difference in a single column data i.e. the Different would be

```
Column C
date 2 (1/2/12) would check the difference from date 1 (1/1/12)
date 3 (1/3/12) would check the difference from date 2 (1/2/12)
date 4 (1/4/12) would check the difference from date 3 (1/3/12)
```

I think i could create two other columns Date days minus -1 and amount then display the difference

```
Column A<date>  Column B<Amount> Column C <Difference>
1/1/12            550             -150
1/2/12            400              300
1/3/12            700             -200
1/4/12            500
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `LEAD` analytic function

```
SELECT  "Column A", 
        "Column B",
        (LEAD("Column B", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "Column A") - "Column B") AS "Difference"
FROM    TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03f86/5)

Other(s)

- [LAG and LEAD Analytic Functions](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php)

Comment: @sgeddes sometimes these functions can be overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using a `CTE` and `RowNum`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT  ColA,
        ColB,
        rownum rn
  FROM    YourTable
  ORDER BY ColA
)
SELECT C.*,
  C.ColB - C2.ColB ColC
FROM CTE C
  LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C.rn = C2.rn + 1
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb128/1).

Good luck.